# Applying operations on multiple column values and storing in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe with about 10 columns and the need is to divide columns with one another and store the result in another dataframe column.

Dataframe looks like -

```
      c1   c2  c3   c4   c5   c6  c7   c8   c9   c10
   0  10  100  200  300  400 500  600  700  800  900
   1  11  110  210  310  410 510  610  710  810  910
   2  12  120  220  320  420 520  620  720  820  920
```

I want to divide col1 with col6 and store its values in new dataframe col, similarly divide col2 with col7 and store the result in another dataframe new col and so on till col5 of x and col10 of y. For eg df2 would contain -

```
      col1   col2   col3    col4    col5   
   0  50     6      3.5     2.66    2.25 
   1  46.3   5.54   3.38    2.61    2.21
   2  43.3   5.16   3.27    2.56    2.19
```

I have used this but it stores one result at a time. For another round I have to re-write another loop .

```
for x, y in zip(df.iloc[:,1:2],df7.iloc[:,6:7]):
df2['col1'] = y/x
```

Following the above code, I get -

```
      col1    
   0  50     
   1  46.3  
   2  43.3
```

I want to have all the 5 columns in df2 at a time. Is there any way where i can use one time run statements to get the result. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example 2/3 columns are fine. Here you haven't provided col7 which is an important one…

Comment: @mozway I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the result you displayed, you tried to divide col6 by col1, col7 by col2 and so on.

You can achieve this using this command:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[['c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10']].values / df[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']].values, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
```

And you should get this result:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50.000000 | 6.000000 | 3.500000 | 2.666667 | 2.250000 |
| 1 | 46.363636 | 5.545455 | 3.380952 | 2.612903 | 2.219512 |
| 2 | 43.333333 | 5.166667 | 3.272727 | 2.562500 | 2.190476 |

In the code example you shared, there is several thing that make your result is wrong:

- First, you don't indent your line after the for loop
- Then, you overwrite the same column all the time: "col1", you need to use a counter to increase the colX each time.

I hope it helps you !